# How can I check for - and get a remainder using fmod (floats)?

Tags: c++, floating-point, fmod

My goal is to check if there is any remainder left when dividing 2 floats, and if there is, give that remainder back to the user.

Given the following code, I had expected that `fmod(2, 0.2)` would be 0, however, I get back `0.2`. I read that this has to do with floating point problems. But is there any way this can be done properly?

```
int main() {
    float a = 2.0;
    float b = 0.2;

    float rem = fmod(a, b);

    if (rem > 0) {
        std::cout << "There is a remainder: " << rem << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "No remainder: " << rem << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output:
`There is a remainder: 0.2`

Comment: To the people who improperly voted to close this as a duplicate of [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken): The fact that floating-point arithmetic uses rounding does not mean you just give up and accept it. This question asks for a solution to a specific problem, and solutions exist and are not discussed in that other question.

Comment: We need to clarify the question. As you may be aware, `.2` in source code is converted to a `double` value that is generally not exactly .2 (and `.2f` is converted to a `float` that is not exactly .2). So, first, is the problem to be solved that you want to know if a `float` `a` is or is not exactly a multiple of a `float` `b`, or you want to know if a `float` `a` is or is not exactly a multiple of some mathematical number *b*? If the latter, what form do you have *b* in—is it always a decimal numeral? Tell us more about the context in which this occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your hunch is correct. `std::fmod` is computing

```
std::fmod(2.0f, 0.20000000298023223876953125f)
```

where the second parameter is the closest IEEE754 (assume your plaform uses that) `float` to `0.2`.

Luckily though mathematical modulus is distributive across multiplication, so you could repose as

```
double rem = (long long)std::round(a * 10) % (long long)std::round(b * 10) / 10.0;
```

using a larger power of 10 according to the number of decimal places required to represent the original problem.

Comment: Thanks mate, just to be sure: shouldn't it be this: `rem = std::min(a, std::abs(rem - 0.2));` (Note `a` instead of `rem`)

Comment: No, my intention was to correct the floating point in another statement.

Comment: I truly appreciate the help mate. In this particular case, after I have casted the result `rem` to float, how would I check if there actually is a remainder? Because the test `rem > 0` currently passes. Should I set it to `rem > 0.001`?

Comment: @Moody: Don't forget to round the `double` to the 14th significant figure before taking the cast.

Comment: Actually I think I prefer the original idea.

Comment: Thanks truly, for the help - unfortunately, it is a bit unclear from your latest edit how I can obtain the remainder (if there is any) to pass the print statement in my question. Is the condition I have in my if statement correct? How can I apply this to your edit?

Comment: Sorry. I'm being a turkey. You need to divide by `10.0` so the expression is the remainder.

Comment: Haha no you're not - and thanks - it appears to work now! I appreciate it man

Comment: *which actually takes double not float arguments* - `fmod()` has overloads for float and long double, btw. C++ isn't like C where you should be using `fmodf()` when working with floats (or the `<tgmath.h>` version).

Comment: @Shawn: Yes the fact that I'm being a turkey is already established - edited. Twice.

Comment: To get similar result to `fmod()`, code here should use `trunc(a*10)`, not `round(a*10)`.

Comment: This is subject to multuple rounding errors. Solutions with no more error than is necessary in the final result exist. For example, if |a|>½, then I think `remainder(remainder(a, 1) + remainder(4*a, 1), 1)/5` may have no error until the final operation, which means its result will be as close as possible to the ideal result (for the symmetric residue, still needs adjustment for `fmod`). Oddly, rounding errors may occur for smaller values. I need to think more about that.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I look forward to seeing that answer. (I'll use my reopen hammer if it's closed as a duplicate again prior to your answering.)